# Delphy Indy10 - TIdUDPClient - Get the IP I receive packet on

Tags: delphi

I have a TIdUDPClient created like this:

```
myUDPClient := TIdUDPClient.Create(nil);
myUDPClient.ReceiveTimeout := 500;
myUDPClient.Binding.Port := 300;
myUDPClient.Active := True;
```

The binding IP is not specified because I have 3 ethernet adapters with dynamic addressing (192.168.x.x, 10.10.x.x and 172.16.x.x), so the binding IP is generated by Indy and it is `0.0.0.0`.
When I receive a packet I can determine the sender IP, but I cannot determine the local IP on which I received the packet (not 0.0.0.0, but one of the 3 IPs assigned to my computer).

Do you know any method to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not assign to `Binding.Port` directly, assign to `myUDPClient.BoundPort` instead and let `TIdUDPClient` assign to `Binding.Port` internally.

Since you are binding to `0.0.0.0` locally, there is no way to determine the destination IP when using `TIdUDPClient` to read the packet, since it uses the socket API `recvfrom()` function, hich does not report that info.  The socket API `getsockname()` function will report `0.0.0.0` because that is what the socket is really bound to.

On Windows XP+, you can use `GStack.ReceiveMsg()` instead to receive packets.  It has a `TIdPacketInfo` output parameter, which contains has a `DestIP` field (you have to use `Binding.SetSockOpt()` to enable `ReceiveMsg()` to collect that info), eg:

```
...
myUDPClient.Active := True;
myUDPClient.Binding.SetSockOpt(IPPROTO_IP, IP_PKTINFO, 1);
```

```
var
  Buffer: TIdBytes;
  BufLen: LongWord;
  PktInfo: TIdPacketInfo;
begin
  SetLength(Buffer, ...);
  BufLen := GStack.ReceiveMsg(myUDPClient.Binding.Handle, Buffer, PktInfo);
  // use Buffer up to BufLen bytes
  // PktInfo.DestIP will be the IP that received the packet
end;
```

Alternatively, you can switch to `TIdUDPServer` instead, and create a separate entry in its `Bindings` collection for each local IP you want to receive packets on:

```
myUDPServer := TIdUDPServer.Create(nil);
myUDPServer.DefaultPort := 300;
myUDPServer.OnUDPRead := UDPRead;

LocalIPs := TStringList.Create;
try
  GStack.AddLocalAddressesToList(LocalIPs);
  for I := 0 to LocalIPs.Count-1 do
    myUDPServer.Bindings.Add.IP := LocalIPs[I];
finally
  LocalIPs.Free;
end;
{
Or this, if you are using an up-to-date Indy 10 snapshot:

LocalIPs := TIdStackLocalAddressList.Create;
try
  GStack.GetLocalAddressList(LocalIPs);
  for I := 0 to LocalIPs.Count-1 do
    myUDPServer.Bindings.Add.SetBinding(LocalIPs[I].IPAddress, myUDPServer.DefaultPort, LocalIPs[I].IPVersion);
finally
  LocalIPs.Free;
end;
}

myUDPServer.Active := True;
```

```
procedure TMyClass.DoUDPRead(AThread: TIdUDPListenerThread; const AData: TIdBytes; ABinding: TIdSocketHandle);
begin
  // ABinding.IP is the local IP address that received this packet...
end;
```